# Unresolved external symbols building Python C extension

Tags: python, dll, swig

I'm currently trying to build a C-extension in Windows.  The errors seem related to not finding 'standard' symbols in the python27.dll.  How do I resolve these missing symbols?  Do I need to somehow tell the compiler where to find python27.dll or is something wrong with my python27.lib?

My setup is the following:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Python 2.7.4
- Numpy 1.7
- Swig 2.0.9
- Visual studio 9.0

I found this link that seems to have a related problem, but with versions of things I'm not using: http://bugs.python.org/issue15772

I'm running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` to build the extension.

The setup.py looks like the following:

```
try:
    numpy_include = numpy.get_include()
except AttributeError:
    numpy_include = numpy.get_numpy_include()

fmm3d_module = Extension('_fmm3d', sources=['fmm3d.i', 'fmm3d.c'],
                         include_dirs = [numpy_include])
```

Everything compiles fine and then runs the following link command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PCbuild\ amd64 /EXPORT:init_fmm3d build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fmm3d_wrap.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fmm3d.obj /OUT:C:\Users\luke\Documents\Ranking\code\_fmm3d.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_fmm3d.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_fmm3d.pyd.manifest
```

I get link errors that relate to Python symbols like the following:

```
fmm3d_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_AsString referenced in function _SWIG_Python_str_AsChar
fmm3d_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromString referenced in function _SWIG_Python_str_FromChar
fmm3d_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_RuntimeError referenced in function _SWIG_Python_ErrorType
fmm3d_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_AttributeError referenced in function _SWIG_Python_ErrorType
```

I've found the Python lib file located at C:Python27\libs\python27.lib.  I assume the symbols are expected to be in here.  In fact, it looks like they are at least referenced in this file.  For example, running `dumpbin -headers C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib` shows the following snippet:

```
  Version      : 0
  Machine      : 8664 (x64)
  TimeDateStamp: 5160619D Sat Apr 06 12:55:41 2013
  SizeOfData   : 0000001F
  DLL name     : python27.dll
  Symbol name  : PyString_AsString
  Type         : code
  Name type    : name
  Hint         : 629
  Name         : PyString_AsString
```

This leads me to believe that the python27.lib says the reference for PyString_AsString is contained in python27.dll.

Is there some other command-line argument I'm missing to locate these symbols?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There should be a python27.lib on the command line. Your dumpbin indicates your python is 64 bit, probably your VC++ compiler is 32 bit.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to see which compiler is 32 vs 64 bits? (I'm a Linux guy, not familiar with Windows build environments at all).  I'm assuming there's a 64-bit compiler on this machine because there is a lot of source that's 64-bit and must have been built on that machine. Also, what argument do I use to 'enable' the python32.dll.  The compiler flags already added the python32.lib automatically file when I ran the setup file.

Comment: I found the .bat file that sets the paths to control which complier to use.  Everything linked correctly after that.  For reference, the setup for the 64-bit builds were located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\vsvarsam64.bat on my system.

Comment: Also, this blog post was helpful in figuring out the differences in the 64-bit and 32-bit environment variables:  http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/

Comment: @durden2.0 Cool, thanks for posting the additional data & link.

Comment: My issue was not quite the same, but your suggestion put me on the correct track. Cheers :)

Comment: fixed link: https://victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/